# How do I enable Application Transport Security (ATS) restrictions

Tags: ios, penetration-testing

How do I, Ensure ATS is enabled within the iOS mobile application so that confidential information sent between the application and the back end servers are secured and not to be intercepted by man­-in­the­-middle style attacks.

Below is what I already set but still Fails for the penetration test.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjhNv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Preventing Man-in-the-Middle Attacks in iOS with SSL Pinning.

Restricting the set of trusted certificates through pinning prevents attackers from analyzing the functionality of the app and the way it communicates with the server.

**Types of SSL Certificate Pinning**

**Pin the certificate**: You can download the server’s certificate and bundle it into your app. At runtime, the app compares the server’s certificate to the one you’ve embedded.

**Pin the public key**: You can retrieve the certificate’s public key and include it in your code as a string. At runtime, the app compares the certificate’s public key to the one hard-coded in your code.

There are multiple blogs available on topic of SSL pinning. for your reference attaching one
[Please go through this to understand SSL pinning](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1484288-preventing-man-in-the-middle-attacks-in-ios-with-ssl-pinning)